# Причины правок как для закрытия

Tags: предложение, правки, предлагаемые-правки

Хорошо бы сделать причины правок как для закрытия. Ведь большинство правок — это:

- Добавления важного тега
- Правка орфографии
- Переформулировка (для повышения ясности того , что спрашивается)
- И иногда (у меня) перевод вопроса для переоткрытия.

Для других причин можно сделать:

- Другое (как и у тревог)

Comment: Набивайте 2 килорепы (или сколько там) и причину вводить не нужно будет

Comment: Канцелярит, как по мне. Комментария к правке вполне достаточно.

Comment: @nomnoms12, так вроде он комментарий и предлагает, только чтоб не руками его писать, а кнопочку тыкнуть - так быстрее.

Comment: @Qwertiy, быстрее вообще ничего не вводить :-) то есть просто лимит . опустить до  0 который требует сейчас введения комментария