# Как привлечь внимание к вопросу на мете?

Tags: обсуждение, мета, конкурс

На основном сайте — объявить конкурс. Но на мете нет такого механизма. Каки есть аналоги?

### Update

Вот [пример вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9889/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f). Хотелось бы привлечь к нему внимания. Может модераторы захотели бы  это реализовать.

Comment: Крикнуть в чат? )))

Comment: А зачем? И какого рода вопрос? Для важных объявлений, к примеру, у нас есть метка [meta-tag:важное].

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9889/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica разве что, в чате попросить людей глянуть вопрос. Других механизмов нет =/

Comment: Пример вопроса в комментариях -- это хорошо, но ещё лучше когда в самом вопросе описано к какому типу вопроса вы хотите добавить внимание: получить поддержку, создать инициативу или что-то иное.

Comment: Ну... не зря ведь написал: ТИП вопроса. Если вы написали "хочу получить поддержку в вопросе" -- мог бы написать полноценный ответ "в этом случае свяжитесь с модераторами", если бы написали "хочу сделать предолжение" -- мог бы ответить "не особо принято продавливать инициативу, но в принципе раз-другой подымите тему в чате". Плюс ответить, что модераторы не программисты движка, не туда пишете. А так -- ну вот в комментариях вам уже ответили, пусть так и остаётся.

Comment: @A K "...что модераторы не программисты движка" —  но вы ведь меняете переводы например, я думал что у вас есть доступ к движку. Ладно задам вопрос на MSE.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica переводы меняются в стороннем сервисе. К движку никто из нас доступа не имеет.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Нет это не дубликат. Здесь вопрос как в принципе привлечь внимание, а не про конкурс.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica последнее предложение из текста моего старого вопроса это по сути весь ваш текущий вопрос.